# chrome app TcpServer and php client

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm use [example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/tcpserver) from Google Team to create a TCP Server using Chrome App Extension API. Sample is work correctly and I connect via telnet and send commands.
When I'm trying to connect to this server from client and try send data. Client connected to server and send data, but server not receive data. Client on PHP, for test I'm using this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php).

What I doing wrong?:(

Thx.

Comment: Add minimal relevant code to the question. Links-only code is not permitted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you have the answer, please enter it into the answer box (answering your own question) so this issue is nicely closed off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve: I'm resolve problem. In php script, after connect need delay. I'm using usleep function. All worked

Worked Example:

```
       $fp = pfsockopen("ip", port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
       if (!$fp) {
           echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
       } else {
         $out = "minimize";
         usleep(125000);
         $r = fputs($fp, $out);
         sleep(1); //
         $out = "restore";
         $r = fputs($fp, $out);
         usleep(125000);
         fclose($fp);
       }
```